# "Ride a bicycle" or "ride on bicycle"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, transitivity

Which is correct, "ride on a bicycle" or "ride a bicycle"?

Comment: @nazar_art: Read [this post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell), then follow [this link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: nazar, John M. Landsberg want (to) say that you might be interested in our new proposal designed specifically for those who want to learn the English language: English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com). On EL&U this kind of questions are considered at best too basic, but on ELL they are welcome. Please, take a look now or, however, be aware that that proposal exists. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ride a bicycle. This is a particular usage of "ride" which implies that one is also "driving" the bicycle.

You would say "ride on a bicycle" only if the person was riding the bicycle and someone else was driving, which might happen if someone was sitting behind the driver, or sitting on the handlebars, for example. Also, if you change the phrasing, "ride on" can become correct, like this: "He took a ride on his bicycle."

Comment: Similar to "ride a horse".